# Jquery error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, syntax

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown-text" id="dropdownopen" onclick="dropdownopen(0)">
    <div class="inside">+ Show Content</div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown" id="dropdownnum(0)">
     <div class="inner">INSERT DROPDOWN CONTENT IN HERE</div>
</div>
```

And here is my JS (Jquery):

```
function dropdownopen(param) {
    $('#dropdownnum('+param+')').fadeOut(300);
}
```

The #dropdownnum(0) div is display:none; by default, so this should work, but I get the error:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #dropdownnum(0).

Comment: the naming of your ids is going to cause issues. consider using classes or just dropdownnum1, dropdownnum2 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have special characters like `(` and `)` in a value of `id`. Please try changing your code to:

```
<div class="dropdown-text" id="dropdownopen" onclick="dropdownopen(0)">
    <div class="inside">+ Show Content</div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown" id="dropdownnum-0">
     <div class="inner">INSERT DROPDOWN CONTENT IN HERE</div>
</div>

function dropdownopen(param) {
    $('#dropdownnum-'+param).fadeOut(300);
}
```

Comment: Are you looking at the HTML4 or HTML5 restrictions. :)

Comment: @epascarello Do you say W3C Working Draft is wrong? http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

Comment: Oh yeah.. That's HTML4. Here's HTML5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attribute-value

Comment: Bro, just leave it. I am giving you an upvote for so much of argument. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The ( and ) needs to be escaped.

```js
function dropdownopen(param) {
    $('#dropdownnum\\('+param+'\\)').fadeOut(300);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-text" id="dropdownopen" onclick="dropdownopen(0)">
    <div class="inside">+ Show Content</div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown" id="dropdownnum(0)">
     <div class="inner">INSERT DROPDOWN CONTENT IN HERE</div>
</div>
```

But you really should pick a different naming scheme for your ids so you do not have to do this.

Comment: Have your vote, better let's not argue for this silly thing. It is better to avoid such a way of writing the values. And you too agree with it. `:)` The OP is doing it unknowingly. It's okay that now they understood.